# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k(k+1)}$

Tags: power-series

My partner is tutoring a Civil Engineering student in maths. Conveniently, I am a civil engineer so when any maths that's confusing comes up, I can usually help out. However, we are having a problem with the summing of power series, one area where I am sorely lacking.

After spending two hours on a question, we still cannot solve it and are always left with a $k$. Admittedly, I don't fully know what I am doing.

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k(k+1)}$.

We do know that the answer is $1 + \dfrac{1-x}{x}\ln (1-x)$.

Any hints or help in the direction to go would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Hints : Telescoping, partial fractions...

Comment: @José-Carlos-Santos Oh thank you, this place is so different to stackoverflow

Comment: @rsadhvika is it perhaps similar to something like this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345983/power-series-by-partial-fractions

Comment: Thanks @RobertZ for the better edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$$
and recall that for $|x|<1$, 
$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}$$
(which can be obtained by term-wise integration of $1/(1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$).
Therefore
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k(k+1)}&=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{k}}{k+1}\\
&=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k}}{k+1}+1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+1\\
&=-\ln(1-x)-\frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x}+1\\
&=1 + \dfrac{1-x}{x}\ln (1-x).\end{align}$$