# power series centered at origin of $\frac{1}{1 - z - 2z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, partial-fractions

I'm working on finding power series of $\frac{1}{1 - z - 2z^2}$. And I found post about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345983/power-series-by-partial-fractions) and The conclusion seems fair enough: $$\frac{1}{1-z-2 z^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k$$ $$a_k = \frac{2}{3} 2^k + \frac{1}{3} (-1)^k$$

But I'm wondering about the radius of convergence. I'm thinking $|z| < R$ with $R = \frac{1}{2}$ would be it since it is the smaller one between $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Is this correct? And can I consider these values to be just like in real numbers? Also, if $|z| < R$ with $R = \frac{1}{2}$ is the right thing, what happens in other points? for example $$$$$|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ but not $z=\frac{1}{2}$ $$$$$\frac{1}{2} < |z| < 1$ $$$$$|z|=1$ but not $z=-1$ $$$$$1 < |z|$

Comment: The radius of convergence is called that because convergence depends only on the magnitude of $z$ (except at the radius of convergence). This is a consequence of the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the radius of convergence is $\frac12$. You can prove that using the fact that$$\frac1{1-z-2z^2}=\frac{1}{3 (z+1)}-\frac{2}{3 (2 z-1)}$$and expanding $\frac1{3(z+1)}$ and $\frac2{3(2z-1)}$ as power series; the first power series converges when $|z|<1$, whereas the second one converges when $|z|<\frac12$.

Comment: Is there a way of finding power series expansion for rest of the complex plane?

Comment: Sure; use the fact that$$\frac1{1-z-2z^2}=\frac1{3\bigl((z-a)+1+a\bigr)}-\frac2{3\bigl(2(z-a)-1+2a\bigr)}.$$